# ASP.NET and IIS and MVC - site does not open

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a web site and when I try to view/access through IIS(Default Web Site -> Search/Run Site -> Search *:80(http)) the site open.

But when I try to open/debug using Visual Studio 2010, the following problem happens:

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /help

If I am in home page(root "/") and I try to open any page, open the "Directory Listing"
What is happening ?

Comment: What is listed on the "Web" page of your MVC Project Properties in VS?

Comment: Use "Virtual Studio Development Server", and port random ...

Comment: That's your problem, you're not using IIS to debug your project. Change your project's Web settings to use IIS instead.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is in your routing (Route.Config). Make sure you change your routing to follow how your website is set up in IIS.